# Getting a JComboBox to Display in a JTable without Clicking it First

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I am trying to understand how to get a JComboBox into a JTable so I am using the demo from the JTable tutorial.

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

/** 
 * TableRenderDemo is just like TableDemo, except that it
 * explicitly initializes column sizes and it uses a combo box
 * as an editor for the Sport column.
 */
public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {
private boolean DEBUG = false;

public TableRenderDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(1,0));

    JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    //Set up column sizes.
    initColumnSizes(table);

    //Fiddle with the Sport column's cell editors/renderers.
    setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));

    //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
    add(scrollPane);
}

/*
 * This method picks good column sizes.
 * If all column heads are wider than the column's cells'
 * contents, then you can just use column.sizeWidthToFit().
 */
private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
    MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
    TableColumn column = null;
    Component comp = null;
    int headerWidth = 0;
    int cellWidth = 0;
    Object[] longValues = model.longValues;
    TableCellRenderer headerRenderer =
        table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

        comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                             null, column.getHeaderValue(),
                             false, false, 0, 0);
        headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

        comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i)).
                         getTableCellRendererComponent(
                             table, longValues[i],
                             false, false, 0, i);
        cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Initializing width of column "
                               + i + ". "
                               + "headerWidth = " + headerWidth
                               + "; cellWidth = " + cellWidth);
        }

        column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
    }
}

public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table,
                             TableColumn sportColumn) {
    //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
    comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
    comboBox.addItem("Knitting");
    comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
    comboBox.addItem("Pool");
    comboBox.addItem("None of the above");
    sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

    //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
            new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
    sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                    "Last Name",
                                    "Sport",
                                    "# of Years",
                                    "Vegetarian"};
    private Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

    public final Object[] longValues = {"Jane", "Kathy",
                                        "None of the above",
                                        new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE};

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    /*
     * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
     * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
     * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
     * rather than a check box.
     */
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * editable.
     */
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
        //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
        if (col < 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * data can change.
     */
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                               + " to " + value
                               + " (an instance of "
                               + value.getClass() + ")");
        }

        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("New value of data:");
            printDebugData();
        }
    }

    private void printDebugData() {
        int numRows = getRowCount();
        int numCols = getColumnCount();

        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Normally the JComboBox does not display until clicked. I want to have it display all the time so the user knows there is a combo box in that column. I have tried custom renderers (some found on this forum) to solve this but ran into problems that took me down a wildly wrong path. Is there an example somewhere that shows how to get the combo box to display without being clicked first. TIA.

Comment: "Display" of a cell content is the responsibility of the `CellRenderer`. I would recommend you take a look at [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: That is NOT an MCVE. I already told you how to create one. Your question is about a renderer for a combo box. So you only need a table with a single column. There is no need for all the debug logic or the "printDebugData()" method, that has nothing to do with your question. There is no need for a custom table model. You can just use a DefaultTableModel and add a custom renderer to a specific column in the table. I told you before the entire `MCVE` would be 20-30 lines of code.

Comment: Then I have no idea what you want. This is the program I am running and trying to get to look the way I want. What else would I possibly post?

Comment: `What else would I possibly post?` - I told you all the debug logic is not necessary. What do you not understand??? I told you a custom TableModel is not needed that you can use a DefaultTableModel. What do you not understand???. The point of a `MCVE` is to simplify the stated problem to as few lines of code as possible. This tells us that you actually understand the question that you are asking and that you nave made an effort to solve the problem. In any case, even with all those problems I still gave you an answer to your question. What do you not understand about that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The renderer would look something like:

```
class ComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer
{
    public ComboBoxRenderer()
    {
        setBorder(null);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        removeAllItems();
        addItem( value );

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bingo! That is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to invoke Combobox editor on first click.

```
JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel()) {
    @Override
    public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, EventObject e){
        boolean result = super.editCellAt(row, column, e);
        if( result ) {
            Component comp = getEditorComponent();
            if( comp instanceof JComboBox ) {
                final JComboBox combo = ( JComboBox ) comp;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        combo.showPopup();
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```